# Preciso exibir um campo de TOTAL em uma query com PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Tenho a query abaixo que retorna a quantidade total em estoque dos produtos para cada cidade. Cada cidade é uma coluna e os produtos são exibidos em linhas.

Agora preciso exibir em um campo (coluna) a soma da quantidade total de cada cidade, como posso fazer? Preciso de uma coluna "Total" e abaixo dela o total de cada produto (que é a soma do total de todas as cidades).

```
SELECT id_product
   ,code
   ,product
   ,[CAMPINAS] AS 'campinas'
   ,[PAULISTA] AS 'paulista'
   ,[BELÉM PA] AS 'belem'
   ,[PORTO ALEGRE] AS 'porto_alegre'
   ,[SALVADOR] AS 'salvador'
   ,[RIO DE JANEIRO] AS 'rio_de_janeiro'
   ,[RECIFE] AS 'recife'
   ,[CURITIBA] AS 'curitiba'
   ,[MANAUS] AS 'manaus'
   ,[JOÃO PESSOA] AS 'joao_pessoa'
   ,[MACEIÓ] AS 'maceio'
   ,[BRASILIA] AS 'brasilia'
   ,[FEIRA DE SANTANA] AS 'feira_de_santana'
   ,[SANTOS] AS 'santos'
   ,[BELO HORIZONTE] AS 'belo_horizonte'
   ,[FORTALEZA] AS 'fortaleza'
FROM (
SELECT id_product
    ,code
    ,product
    ,franchise
    ,quantity
FROM VW_ViewPosicaoEstoque
WHERE id_franchise IN 
        (
        SELECT id
        FROM t_franchises
        WHERE id = 1
            OR enum_franchise_user_type = 2
        )
     ) C
PIVOT(AVG(quantity) FOR franchise IN (
        [CAMPINAS]
        ,[PAULISTA]
        ,[BELÉM PA]
        ,[PORTO ALEGRE]
        ,[SALVADOR]
        ,[RIO DE JANEIRO]
        ,[RECIFE]
        ,[CURITIBA]
        ,[MANAUS]
        ,[JOÃO PESSOA]
        ,[MACEIÓ]
        ,[BRASILIA]
        ,[FEIRA DE SANTANA]
        ,[SANTOS]
        ,[BELO HORIZONTE]
        ,[FORTALEZA]
        )) AS P
GO
```

Comment: Você indicou a tag de 3 SGDB diferentes, em cada um pode ser uma sintaxe... em qual banco você utilizará essa query?

Comment: @CamiloSantos Utilizarei a query em SQL Server

Answer (score -1):

Consegui!

Só fazer a soma de cada cidade e inserir em qualquer lugar antes do FROM:

```
,[CAMPINAS] + [PAULISTA] + [BELÉM PA] + [PORTO ALEGRE] + [SALVADOR] + [RIO DE JANEIRO] + 
[RECIFE] + [CURITIBA] + [MANAUS] + [JOÃO PESSOA] + [MACEIÓ] + [BRASILIA] +
[FEIRA DE SANTANA] + [SANTOS] + [BELO HORIZONTE] + [FORTALEZA] AS 'Total'
```

Comment: Na expressão de soma das cidades, basta que uma única coluna tenha ausência de informação (isto é, NULL) para que o resultado final seja NULL. // Sugestão: Coalesce(CAMPINAS, 0) + Coalesce(PAULISTA, 0) + ...

Comment: @JoséDiz Maravilha! vou utilizar sua sugestão! Muito obrigado